# Table dump using pg_dump fails in AWS Redshift when table column includes reserved keyword

Tags: amazon-redshift

My goal is to dump the table structure for all tables in the database without any contents.

I have some Redshift tables that include reserved keywords. If I try to dump them I get this error:

```
pg_dump -sc --quote-all-identifiers -h example.com -p 5439 -d redacted -U redacted --table public.mytable > ./blah.txt
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query failed: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "stdout"
LINE 1: ... "status", "date") TO stdout;
                                 ^
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query was: COPY "public"."mytable" ("status", "date") TO stdout;
```

If I try to export just the table structure using `pg_dump -sc --quote-all-identifiers -h example.com -p 5439 -d redacted -U redacted --table public.mytable > ./blah.txt` then the command succeeds, but the resulting file contains this create table statement:

```
CREATE TABLE "mytable" (
);
```

With nothing inside the parentheses aside from a new line.

The pg_dump version is `pg_dump (PostgreSQL) 9.5.8` on Ubuntu 16.04.

The issue affects several different tables and one of the things in common among those tables is having columns named with words on the [psql reserved words list](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.3/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html). Maybe there's another explanation for why this is happening, so I'd love to hear alternate theories of the problem.

While it would be nice, I cannot change the names of the columns in the tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strongly recommend that you shouldn't use `pg_dump` for Redshift. Try the `UNLOAD` command instead. 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html

Comment: Agreed, UNLOAD is the way to go on Redshift.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I had failed to clarify that my goal is really just to dump the table structures for use in a development environment. I don't want any data, I just want the "CREATE TABLE ..." commands so I can have a local schema that matches production. It doesn't seem like UNLOAD matches that purpose. I upvoted your answer because it does address the question before I had clarified it.

Comment: Have a look at this view which generates the full Redshift DDL for a given table. Other views are available for other object types. https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/blob/master/src/AdminViews/v_generate_tbl_ddl.sql

Comment: That's an interesting solution and I had seen that. I dismissed it as I hoped a pg_dump solution would be fast, but if it doesn't work then it's not worth much. I'll also consider switching to that awslabs solution.